# PHP serial works on windows, but not on linux

Tags: php, linux, windows, apache

I have a PHP script that I am trying to run via Apache on Linux. The script use PHP Serial to send a notification to a paging system using the TAP protocol. The issue is the script does not work on Linux whether I localhost the PHP file or remote in. The Script works on Windows but does not work on Linux

I have tried swapping the serial port from the USB serial to a real serial port and this did not work, I have tried running it from the server itself and from a remote connection and nether worked, I have tried changing the code to just send a message over the serial port I was unable to send the message with PHP, I have tried receiving messages over the port using python and was able to send a message to the port and get one using python so the port is working.

```php
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
include "php_serial.class.php";

$pagerSerial = new phpSerial();
$pagerSerial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyUSB0");
$pagerSerial->confBaudRate(9600);
$pagerSerial->confParity("none");
$pagerSerial->confCharacterLength(8);
$pagerSerial->confStopBits(1);
$pagerSerial->confFlowControl("none");


$pagerSerial->deviceOpen();


$msg_to = 102;
$msg_text = "Test"; 

$message = chr(2).$msg_to.chr(13).$msg_text.chr(13).chr(3);
$checksum = calcChecksum($message);
$message .= $checksum.chr(13);
$CR = chr(13);
$end = chr(27).chr(4).chr(13);
$login = chr(27)."PG1".chr(13);

$pagerSerial->sendMessage($CR);
sleep(2);
$pagerSerial->sendMessage($message);
sleep(2);
$pagerSerial->sendMessage($end);


function calcChecksum($message) {
$split = str_split($message); $sum = 0;
foreach ($split as $value) { $numb = ord($value); $sum += $numb; }
$d3 = 48 + $sum - intval($sum / 16) * 16;
$sum = intval($sum / 16);
$d2 = 48 + $sum - intval($sum / 16) * 16;
$sum = intval($sum / 16);
$d1 = 48 + $sum - intval($sum / 16) * 16;
return chr($d1).chr($d2).chr($d3);
};
```

I don't get why it works on windows, but not Linux.
When I use python I can get the port working with pyserial.
I have not been able to get the script working on python, but I have been trying. In the end it would be best to have it working in PHP for the interface I am trying to setup in the long run. Any clue why it would work in one OS, but not the other?

Edit:
Could the Chrs be different between the systems? I think that window and linux handle character returns differently, but I just need to send that data in order for pager system to understand the TAP protocol I am sending.

Comment: files etc. are **case-sensitive** in UNIX-based systems (for good reason) - Windows is more of a free-for-all with file names for some reason. Make sure files names match EXACTLY - not just on text

Comment: ya the file is the same for both systems and I am calling it the same on both of them. It's all lowercase. I am running the php file fine and loading the site, but it is just not sending anything over the serial port.

Comment: Linux may need `chr(10)` instead of `chr(13)` or with it. See if changing `$CR = chr(13);` to `$CR = chr(13) . chr(10);` or `$CR = chr(10);` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Ya making those changes does not seem to help at all. Are you saying change ti for just the CR? or all the chr(13)s?

Comment: Okay So the chr(10) was needed, I also just had an issue with the port. Thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows handles returns as chr(13).chr(10) by default so on linux you need to add the chr(10) in order to have TAP be able to use the return. As mentioned by user Dave. Adding this at comment to close it.